# Get intersection of all values from a dictionary with lists

Tags: python-3.x

I have a dictionary which contains key-value pairs where the key is a string and the value is stored as a list.

I am looking to get the intersection of all the elements in the lists of each entry in the dictionary.

For instance, if I had a dictionary like this:

```
athletes = {"athlete_A" : [16,43,34,23], "athlete_B": [23,60,80,75]}
```

I would like to get the list `[23]`. I can find solutions on intersection of dictionaries, but I don't seem to find how to work with only the values of a dict.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `functools.reduce` and set intersection:

```
from functools import reduce

reduce(set.intersection, map(set, athletes.values()))
# {23}
```

If there are duplicates within your lists and you want to catch all (e.g. if two `23`s occur in each list), you can use [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) intersection instead:

```
from collections import Counter

[*reduce(Counter.__and__, map(Counter, athletes.values())).elements()]
# [23]
```

Answer (score 1):

Create set from the first athlete's list

```
A_as_set = set(athletes['athlete_A'])
intersection = A_as_set.intersection(athletes['athlete_B'])
intersection_as_list = list(intersection)
```

Source [HERE](https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-find-common-elements-between-two-lists-in-python) for intersection and [HERE](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm) for dictionary

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion - how would you implement this for more than 2 athletes? I would ideally like to have it working with any number of dictionary entries

Comment: Are you searching one data that appears in all athletes' lists or are you searching for athlete pairs that has same values in their lists?